# only print numbers in list between x and y

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out of there is a library I can use to identify if a number is between two numbers, or if I have to iterate through every number with a for loop and an if condition

```
def get_numbers_in_between(li, x, y):
    # x can be bigger than y or vice versa
    if x > y:
        big = x
        small = y
    else:
        big = y
        small = x

    nums_in_between = [n for n in li if (n >= small and n <= big)]
    return nums_in_between


print(get_numbers_in_between([9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21], 20, 10))
```

output:

```
[10, 11, 15, 19, 20]
```

Is there a library that will automatically figure out which is bigger/smaller (x,y), and take the list as an input and return a new list with the numbers between?

Comment: Uhm, uh range()?

Comment: You don't need a library for this, it's just python. If it couldn't make numerical comparisons, it wouldn't be a language. You just need to know how to put it into code

Comment: and where would the list go in range()?

Comment: everyone is ignoring your actual question I think, just use `small, large = sorted([x, y])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
def get_numbers_in_between(l,x,y):
    return [i for i in l if i in range(min(x,y), max(x,y)+1)]

get_numbers_in_between([9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21], 20, 10)   # [10, 11, 15, 19, 20]
```

Comment: So far, I think this is the best solution, because it doesn't care if the order of x/y is bigger/smaller, just in between the two numbers.

Answer (score 3):

if you start from a given list and need to extract the ones that satisfy a contition:

```
lst = [9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21]
print([n for n in lst if 10 <= n <= 20])
```

and if you need all the integers its just

```
list(range(10, 20+1))
```

if you need to sort the max an min first, this is an option:

```
def get_numbers_in_between(li, x, y):
    mx, mn = sorted((x, y))
    return [n for n in li if mx <= n <= mn]

print(get_numbers_in_between(li=[9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21], x=20, y=10))
```

Comment: This solution was also really helpful, as I have two sets of numbers in my actual problem. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`,

```
>>> nums
[9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21]
>>> sorted_list = sorted(nums) # easier to find min, max ?
>>> min_, max_ = sorted_list[0], sorted_list[-1]
>>> filter(lambda x: min_ < x < max_, nums)
[10, 11, 15, 19, 20]
```

And there's is similar `itertools.ifilter` in `python2`,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: 10 <= x <= 20, nums))
[10, 11, 15, 19, 20]
```

And in `itertools.filterfalse` in `python3`,

```
>>> list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: not (10 <= x <= 20), nums))
[10, 11, 15, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be as simple as suggested:

```
small = 8
big = 16
nums_in_between = [n for n in li if n in range(small, big)]
```

Answer (score 0):

with help from roganjosh - good one!

```
dat=np.random.randint(0,20,50)
x=5
y=10
ans=dat[(dat>=x) & (dat<y)]
print(ans)
```

old (with np.where):

```
import numpy as np
dat=np.random.randint(0,20,50)
x=5
y=10
ans=dat[np.where((dat>=x) & (dat<y))]
print(ans)
```

Comment: `dat[(dat >= x) & (dat < y)]` would do, but then you have the overhead of converting to an array in the first place

Comment: You still don't need `np.where`. You can create the mask without it.

Comment: `ans = dat[dat[(dat>=x) & (dat<y)]]` but this still requires the import of a heavy dependency (numpy) that the OP never mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**OP**: *automatically figure out which is bigger/smaller (x,y), and take the list as an input and return a new list with the numbers between?*

**Generic method**:

```
def GetNumbersInBetween(lst, l_Bound, u_Bound):
    n_List = []

    lowerBound = min(l_Bound, u_Bound)   # Get the lower val
    upperBound = max(l_Bound, u_Bound)   # Get the higher val

    for x in lst:
        if x >= lowerBound and x <= upperBound:
            n_List.append(x)
    return n_List

lst = [9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21]

lowerBound = 20       # intentionally given the wrong value
upperBound = 10       # intentionally given the wrong value

print(GetNumbersInBetween(lst, lowerBound, upperBound))
```

**OR**

Using `list comprehension`:

```
print([x for x in lst if min(lowerBound,upperBound) <= x <= max(lowerBound,upperBound)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[10, 11, 15, 19, 20]
```